# qtreeview with large data from network

Tags: qt, qtreeview

i want to add items of qstringlist into multi columns treeview  but when the data is to large or the rate of data arrival increases the qtreeview is unresponsive and it takes so much memory

```
smodel =new QStandardItemModel(1,8,this);
smodel->setHeaderData(0,Qt::Horizontal,QObject::tr("Num"));
smodel->setHeaderData(1,Qt::Horizontal,QObject::tr("Time"));
smodel->setHeaderData(2,Qt::Horizontal,QObject::tr("Length"));
smodel->setHeaderData(3,Qt::Horizontal,QObject::tr("Source IP"));
smodel->setHeaderData(4,Qt::Horizontal,QObject::tr("Source Port"));
smodel->setHeaderData(5,Qt::Horizontal,QObject::tr("Protocol"));
smodel->setHeaderData(6,Qt::Horizontal,QObject::tr("Destination IP"));
smodel->setHeaderData(7,Qt::Horizontal,QObject::tr("Destination Port"));
ui->treeView->setModel(smodel);
void MainWindow::showPacket(QString pckt)
{
    QStringList columns= pckt.split("\t");
    if(columns.size()<8)
        return;
     QList<QStandardItem *> preparedRow =prepareRow(columns)  ;
     smodel->appendRow(preparedRow);
     ui->treeView->scrollToBottom();
}


QList<QStandardItem *> MainWindow::prepareRow(QStringList pckt)
{
    QList<QStandardItem *> rowItems;
    rowItems << new QStandardItem(pckt[0]);
    rowItems << new QStandardItem(pckt[1]);
    rowItems << new QStandardItem(pckt[2]);
    rowItems << new QStandardItem(pckt[3]);
    rowItems << new QStandardItem(pckt[4]);
    rowItems << new QStandardItem(pckt[5]);
    rowItems << new QStandardItem(pckt[6]);
    rowItems << new QStandardItem(pckt[7]);
    return rowItems;
}
```

Comment: i really wanted to do as u said but i really dont know how and i needed example to show me how to but the qstringlist into a row in the qtreeview , i hope if u can provide me with example of how to do it and how it would look like plz

Answer (score 0):

Creating new `QStandardItem` for each entry produces huge overhead. I think you should subclass `QAbstractItemModel` and provide your own implementation. Your data can be stored in one `QList<QStringList>` variable. You will not need to create an object for each entry. Please refer to `QAbstractItemModel` docs for more information about subclassing.

Comment: Good hint, I'd also profile the whole application, just in case receiving and processing the data is the bottleneck that makes the UI block.

Comment: i really wanted to do as u said but i really dont know how and i needed example to show me how to but the qstringlist into a row in the qtreeview using your solution

Answer (score 0):

Check [QTreeView memory consumption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857008/qtreeview-memory-consumption)

Pretty old, but, it seems to apply.

Try to adapt your data to a QTableView before making a custom model. If using a table solves your problems you will know that with your custom model QTreeView won't still work smooth.

Also, from QTreeView doc:

> Improving Performance It is possible to give the view hints about the
>   data it is handling in order to improve its performance when
>   displaying large numbers of items. One approach that can be taken for
>   views that are intended to display items with equal heights is to set
>   the **uniformRowHeights** property to true.

Comment: i'm having a problem with data() in abstactitemmodel
                if (role == Qt::DisplayRole && index.isValid()) {
                    QStringList *pkt=static_cast<QStringList*>(index.internalPointer());
            
                    if (index.column() == 0)
                        return pkt->at(0);

Comment: As i said, before creating your custom model, rearrange your data on a plain QStandardItemModel and use a QTableView.( This is much more faster to do ) If it suddenly works smooth, you'll know it's a problem of QTreeView and not of your data